# Can you explain meaning this sentence please?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, learning

"You can never place enough emphasis upon the importance of safety"

what does this mean, there is safety is more important than anything.
Am I correct or not?
If not ,can you explain me please?

Thankyou

Comment: However much you emphasise it, it is never too much emphasis.

Comment: It's slightly clumsy / verbose phrasing (for example, ***emphasis*** and ***importance*** convey exactly the same meaning, so there's no point in including both). But all it means is that it's impossible for you to emphasize safety as much as you *should*. It's exaggeration, obviously, but the implication is that safety is "infinitely important".

Answer (score 1):

Saying 'you can't [do something] too much' is a fairly common way of emphasising the importance of repetition. In the case of your example, *safety* is what is important, and reminders about safety require repetition.

Variations of this tend to use 'you can never *have* too much / too many' of something.

Answer (score 0):

This can be stated another way: "You can never emphasize the importance of safety too much."

It means that safety should be emphasized very strongly. It's also a case of dramatic overstatement for effect. If safety is overemphasized nothing will be done because it might be unsafe, but it's still a fairly common sentiment used to counteract the tendency to ignore safety if it's inconvenient.